# Como manter a proporção da tela após ser redimensionada pelo usuário?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, redimensionamento

Preciso restringir uma certa proporção de um JFrame para que a disposição do que eu quero exibir nela não fique distorcida, mas não gostaria de ter que bloquear o redimensionamento com `setRezisable()`. A proporção minima que to testando é de 350x500(7:10 de ratio), mas gostaria de manter essa proporção sempre que a tela tiver o tamanho alterado.

Fiz um exemplo para ver como fica:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class KeepAspectRatioTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int WIDTH = 350;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

            KeepAspectRatioTest screen = new KeepAspectRatioTest();
            screen.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public KeepAspectRatioTest() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setTitle("Keep Aspect Ratio");

        JPanel board = new JPanel();
        board.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.black));


        JPanel sidePanel = new JPanel();
        sidePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.red));
        sidePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(sidePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        sidePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH/6, HEIGHT));

        add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(sidePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }
}
```

Como faço para manter a proporção da tela após ser  redimensionada?

P.S.: acredito que precise utilizar uma `ComponentListener`, só não sei como controlar isso com esse listener, ainda mais porque, ao permitir redimensionamento, também é habilitado que a tela seja maximizada.

Comment: Qual o motivo do negativo? Eu nao posso mais ter uma dúvida no site? Negativar apenas não me ajuda a perceber o quanto minha dúvida *"não demonstra esforço de pesquisa, não é clara ou não é útil"*.

Comment: Cara, tentei resolver o seu problema de várias formas, tanto as elegantes quanto as gambiarradas e não consegui ainda. Fico surpreso como é que uma coisa dessa parece não ter solução simples. Quando/se conseguir isso, posto uma resposta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu vi algumas resposta no SOEn, mas nenhuma de fato consegue resolver isso, ao que parece. Em uma delas, é sugerido reescrever a classe de redimensionamento da janela na mão para restringir isso.

Comment: Também revirei o SOen e tentei mexer com detalhes internos de `java.awt.Window` e não consegui.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o `componentResized` do `componentListener` para realizar o cálculo conforme o *ratio*. Lembre que o *ratio* é 10:7 ou aproximadamente 1.42 para ficar na horizontal ou 7:10 = 0.7 para ficar na vertical. Funciona para `conteiners` e `painels`. Ex:

```
public class AspectRatio {
    static final double RATIO = 0.7;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
        innerPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        final JPanel container = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        container.add(innerPanel);
        container.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                resizePreview(innerPanel, container);
            }
        });
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("AspectRatio");
        frame.getContentPane().add(container);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void resizePreview(JPanel innerPanel, JPanel container) {
        int width = container.getWidth();
        int height = container.getHeight();
        float currentAspectRatio = (float) width / height;

        if (currentAspectRatio > RATIO) {
                 width = (int) (height * RATIO);
        } else {
                 height = (int) (width / RATIO);
        }
        innerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        container.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Se quiser manter aspecto do `Jframe` em si, você precisa sobrescrever o método `paint()` do `JFrame`, mas irá funcionar somente se for redimensionado pelos cantos. Vale lembrar que não é uma boa aproximação, já que o usuário deveria ter controle total sobre o redimensionamento da janela, o que deveria manter o aspecto é o conteúdo dentro da mesma:

```
public class AspectRatio {
    static final double RATIO = 1.42;
    static JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
        innerPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        final JPanel container = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        container.add(innerPanel);

        frame = new JFrame("AspectRatio") {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                resizePreview(frame);
            };
        };
        frame.getContentPane().add(container);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void resizePreview(JFrame jFrame) {
        int width = jFrame.getWidth();
        int height = jFrame.getHeight();
        float currentAspectRatio = (float) width / height;

        if (currentAspectRatio > RATIO) {
            width = (int) (height * RATIO);
        } else {
            height = (int) (width / RATIO);
        }
        jFrame.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        jFrame.revalidate();
        jFrame.repaint();
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Certo, coloquei as duas para outros usuários não confundirem, já que a maioria utiliza horizontal 10:7 mas no exemplo está 7:10. A maximização chama também o `componentResized`, então sem problemas.

Comment: Funciona para o `JFrame` também, só troque o `setPreferredSize` por `setSize`. Vou adicionar na resposta.

Comment: Consegui remover o flickering, utilizando o método `paint()` do Jframe. Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Já tentou redimensionar pelos cantos?

Comment: O meio termo mais óbvio é deixar a janela (`JFrame`) liberado juntamente com um `JScrollPane` para o SO e usuário, e somente manter a proporção do conteúdo. Assim a resolução não fica única e não permite o usuário mudar de qualquer jeito. Mas você simplesmente pode não querer assim. Então o mais próximo que consegui foi pelo `paint()` do`JFrame`. Talvez alguém venha com um jeito melhor.

Comment: Agradeço pela tentativa, mas a primeira solução pelo componentResized acaba funcionando melhor que a do paint(), que só redimensiona em 4 direções e acaba "zoando" mais quando se tenta.